# Preventing CSRF when using GWT's RequestFactory

Tags: gwt, csrf, requestfactory

I've just started porting my GWT-RPC code to the new `RequestFactory` mechanism.

In order to prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF), my GWT-RPC code grabbed the session id that had been stored in a cookie, and included it in the payload of the request. Is that possible with `RequestFactory`?

I understand that there are four mandatory Locator methods, including `findEntity(id_type id)`; so I'm thinking: oh dear: where do I put my session id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, you'll extend `DefaultRequestTransport` to add the token to the request (such as a custom header, but you could also add it to the request body) and pass it to the `init` of your `RequestFactory`. On the server-side, you'll either use a servlet filter or you'll extend `RequestFactoryServlet` to process the token before even processing the RequestFactory request. You're free to define your own "protocol" here: e.g. returning a 403 or 401 status (or whatever) and then process it in the `RequestTransport` to communicate the result to your app.

Comment: Cool. The server-side stuff doesn't phase me, but extending DefaultRequestTransport is a bit daunting. Would I perhaps add the session id as a header on the RequestBuilder?

Comment: The easiest way is indeed to add it as a header (hence my comment in parentheses: "such as a custom header, but you could also add it to the request body").