# CSRF token generation in GWT RequestFactory based app

Tags: gwt, csrf, requestfactory

including a CSRF prevention token in POST requests and validating it on the server by overriding DefaultRequestTransport and RequestFactoryServlet seems to be simple enough.

However, I have one remaining issue: How can I generate the token and get it to the client the first place?

It is quite possible, ney likely, that I have missed something obvious. I am assuming that I need to create the token when the session is created on the server, store it in the session and pass it to the client.

The client then stores the token in a cookie and passes the token in request headers from that point onwards.

Is there a filter of some sort which I can use to provide the tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using RPC, you can read this [document](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html), it has example code for implementing it.

For RF, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227436/preventing-csrf-when-using-gwts-requestfactory) could be helpful.

Comment: thanks, yes, I've seen that question and I understand how to pass the token back to the server for verification. What's stumping me is how to generate the token in the first place. Surely the token has to be generated on the server and passed down at some point? otherwise how does the server know if the token is legit or not? Or am I being dense?

Comment: I would use a `Filter`, this filter would get the token sent by the client in a header, and validate it against the last user's token stored in a session object. Then emit a new one, store in the session and send  a cookie in the response. The client would use the new token in the next request.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty sure I'm being slow and missing something obvious at this point. All these solutions rely on the client sending a token which matches one stored in the session on the server. How does the client get the token in the first place?

Comment: The client gets the token reading a cookie, if the cookie is not, the client can send a void request so as the filter sets it the first time. You can use as well a hidden image or script whose src points to a servlet in your server setting the very first token.

Answer (score 0):

The server generates a random token on the first request and typically includes it in the download of the script.